# Email Template Based on Payment Method Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to use separate email templates for orders depending on the payment method selected.

I have looked around but not found anything to achieve this so I started trying to build a module to handle this.

I have started with overwriting the function configureEmailTemplate() within Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder

```
protected function configureEmailTemplate()
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
     */

    if ($this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() == "LEASING") {
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier("leasingid");
    } else {
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->templateContainer->getTemplateId());
    }
    
    $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->templateContainer->getTemplateId());
    $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions($this->templateContainer->getTemplateOptions());
    $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars($this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars());
    $this->transportBuilder->setFrom($this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity());
}
```

This is an example of what I want to achieve. I am unsure how I can call this checkoutSession data so have added

```
     use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
```

and

```
    protected $_checkoutSession;
```

So I can determine my payment method. Then set the template based on that payment method using something like below.

```
if ($this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() == "LEASING") {
    $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier("leasingid");
}
```

I have been trying to get a message to log, to begin with, but nothing is showing. I would like to know if this is the correct way to go about achieving this before i invest lots of time in figuring this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

- Create an module for override core code. In this case **Custom_Override**
- File `app/code/Custom/Override/etc/di.xml`

  ```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Custom\Override\Model\Email\Sender\OrderSender"/>
  </config>
  ```
- Class `Custom\Override\Model\Email\Sender\OrderSender`

  ```
  <?php
  namespace Custom\Override\Model\Email\Sender;

  use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

  class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
  {
     protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
     {
         parent::prepareTemplate($order);

         //Get Payment Method
         $paymentMethod = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();

         //Define email template for each payment method
         switch ($paymentMethod) {
             case 'cashondelivery' : $templateId = 'custom_template_cod'; break;
             case 'checkmo' : $templateId = 'custom_template_checkmo'; break;
             // Add cases if you have more payment methods
             default:
                 $templateId = $order->getCustomerIsGuest() ?
                     $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId()
                     : $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();

         }

         $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
     }

   }
  ```

Comment: Thankyou! Yeah this seems to be good. I am having an issue with the default case however not sending emails.

Comment: Nope that seems all good email got lost somewhere and arrived a little late i think all working now. Thanks so much this is perfect.

Comment: You're welcome :).  I think Magento 2 still set order emails into queue and run cron to send them

Comment: Override is a bad practice. You should avoid that. Use plugin for a ```\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template::getTemplateId``` (afterGetTemplateId) and modify templateId as you need